# Querying by object property in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

I have an owl ontology for questions and answers knowledge base.
The supperClasse is (thing) has two classes **questions** and **answers** and I have an Object Property **hasAnswers**.
so the result is `questions hasAnswer answers` .
I want to display the answer of specific question.
I tried `SELECT * WHERE {?questions :hasAnswer ?answers}` but it's not working.
how to do this i'm stuck

Comment: Do you have an error you can share or a sample of the result.

Comment: the problem that it gives me nothing when I test it on SPRQL query tab in  protege

Comment: check the prefix declarations. I mean, you have to declare the prefix `:` in the query. You can also use the full URI of the property `hasAnswer` to see that it's just an issue wth the prefix

Comment: thay said, do you have any instance data in your ontology? I mean any particular question with its answer?